# single-page-application React route URLs using Express. But NOT using create-react-app or deployment services like Heroku

Tags: reactjs, express, single-page-application

My problem is very common: I have a single page React application, everything works fine but the URL sub pages won't load if navigated to directly or refreshed.

I spent hours (maybe days) searching and many of the forum posts/articles/tutorials written about this problem presuppose the use of a deployment platform like Heroku or Digital Ocean which either do some of the work for you or maybe have some obfuscating related work that I can't parse out to make sense for my particular application.

The discussion that doesn't involve special deployment platforms always assumes I created my app using create-react-app, which I didn't. I tried to recreate the process in create-react-app that makes single-page-application routing work properly (`npm build` is programmed to make `node` run `react-scripts.js` from `packages/react-scripts/bin`, but the code in react-scripts.js is at once a little more advanced than my skill level and also seems to involve other aspects of create-react-app-- which, again, I didn't use-- so I gave up on that.)

I knew very little about back-end programming before I started this process. Now I've taken a course on node.js and MongoDB (I now realize Mongo has absolutely nothing to do with what I'm trying to do). I'm currently taking a course in Express, but I'm still kinda out to sea in what I'm almost certain has an extremely simple solution.

I'm hoping someone can either: a) explain what I'm missing; b) direct me to a source that will explain but DOESN'T use a special deployment platform or create-react app; or c) just tell me the line or two of code I'm missing (I'm pretty sure it will end up being just a line or two).

I built my site using Gulp as my task runner and everything worked great locally (eg. refreshing and directly accessing a sub-page URL like localhost:3000/about worked).

The Gulpfile code responsible for this is:

```
const browserSync = require('browser-sync');
const historyApiFallback = require('connect-history-api-fallback');

function bs() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: './'
        },
        middleware: [historyApiFallback()]
    })
};
```

It's probably obvious to you that--this being my setup-- trying to directly access the React routing through URLs would cease to work when simply uploading the site folder to a cPanel file host and expecting it to work like it did locally, but back then I didn't know any better.

I'm now trying to use Express to setup my server.js file to make the single page application routing work. I've already told node to run server.js in my package.json. This is what my server.js file looks like:

```
var express = require('express')
var path = require('path')
var history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');

var app = express()

app.use(history());

app.use(express.static(__dirname))

app.get('*', function (req, res) {

     // I've fiddled with this part a million 
    //different ways but can't seem to get it to work 
    //because including lines like 'alert('WORKING') or 
    //res.alert('WORKING') in here never result in an alert 
    //pop-up when entering a URL

     res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html'))
})

var PORT = process.envPORT || 8080
app.listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log('Production Express server running at localhost: ' + PORT)
})
```

Ultimately I want URLs like www.mysite.com/about/ to load the page and the '/about' route from my React router, but at this point I would settle for any and all direct URL requests to just forward to www.mysite.com/index, which I also have tried and failed to do.

Perhaps it's best to word your answer like you're talking to a child.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking in the wrong places right now. Remember that React is the interface between the user and the browser (aside from your content distribution network (cdn) but we're not interested in that at just yet). Your server interfaces with the browser (React). NOT the user. Your express server exists to feed data to your SPA. Routing is controlled by React.

As you discovered, direct routing doesn't work because your website technically only have a single `index.html` file that React piggybacks off of. This means two things:

1. React has to be able to interpret different routes
2. Every possible url pointed to your domain has to directly access `index.html`.

#### SPA routing with `react-router`

For the first issue, you need explicit routing logic. That is what the npm package `react-router` is for.

#### Modifying your domain host settings to always point to `index.html` regardless of any url the user types in

For the second, you have to set up your domain host to route correctly. If you visit anything other than `index.html`, you get a `404`. You use that to your advantage and set up your host to redirect a `404` straight to `index.html`. It's a little on the hacky side, but that's how things are done (except with hash history, which we can get to later).
[image]

#### Sidestepping host config and only need `react-router`, using `hashHistory`

If you want to sidestep the host config modifications, you can use `react-router`'s `hashHistory` instead of `browserHistory`. It creates `/#/` between your domain and any other routes, which lets you sidestep the `index.html` `404` routing. The disadvantage to this is you get "ugly" urls.

`my-website.com/#/a_route`

`my-website.com/#/another_route`

Good luck

Comment: If the solution lies in the react-router npm package then this will be a real Wizard of Oz ending to my journey...

I did use the react-router package in my project (actually I used react-router-dom, but my understanding is it does everything react-router does. source: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4648#issuecomment-284479720 ).

The official documentation at npmjs.com for both packages is very sparse.

I was aware I could use hashes, but as you said it's ugly. It's also shameful that I can't figure out how to do it without them.

Comment: I'll look into setting my domain host settings to redirect all requests to index.html ... unless you have other tips on how I might make/learn to make the route URL's work properly?

Comment: Using only `react-router` without `hashHistory` is impossible, as far as I'm aware of. Your website fundamentally doesn't have multiple pages. Everything has to run `index.html`